# query a list of ids in Python via simple-salesforce

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

I've been trying to query a list of ids from salesforce in Python, here is my code:

```
def query_task():
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\jet.cai\Desktop\TaskContact.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for rowx in range(sheet.nrows):
    task_id = sheet.row_values(rowx, start_colx=0, end_colx=None)[0]
    new_task_id = "'" + task_id + "'"
    task_result = sf.query(format_soql("SELECT Id, WhoId FROM Task WHERE Id = {new_task_id}", new_task_id))
    print(task_result)
```

As you can tell, the task_id comes from excel file, I iterate the first column and reformat it so that the soql query can be executed, however, the error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\jet.cai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\string.py", line 229, in get_value
return kwargs[key]
  KeyError: 'new_task_id'
```

I can understand this format_soql function can only take in **kwargs. Well, can anybody help me out to get the right result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing your ID as a keyword arg:

```
task_result = sf.query(format_soql(
    "SELECT Id, WhoId FROM Task WHERE Id = {task_id}", 
    task_id=task_id))
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#queries), it appears the quoting is done automatically, so you can skip the `new_task_id = "'" + task_id + "'"` step.

Comment: I've also tried, the error is Response content: [{'message': "\nSELECT Id, WhoId FROM Task WHERE Id = '\\'Id\\''\n                                 ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:34\ninvalid ID field: 'Id'", 'errorCode': 'INVALID_QUERY_FILTER_OPERATOR'}]

Comment: @晓天蔡 I think the issue is that you are quoting your query unnecessarily. Change `new_task_id = "'" + task_id + "'"` to `new_task_id = task_id` or just use `task_id` directly.

Comment: @cs95great mind thinks alike, however, it still doesn't work lol, same error pops up.

Comment: @晓天蔡 Maybe the issue is your column names, namespace etc. I haven't used sf in ages, so I'm stumped. Looks like this solves the error in your question, however ;-)

Comment: exactly this is it, I just recalled my first column is filled with literal 'id' hh....
Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use `sf.format_soql`, or have a look here: https://www.oktana.com/python-and-salesforce/